# how to do migrations dynamically in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Is there any way that we can create an create an input field dynamically in the form without doing manually work, like first create the particular field in model and then run `makemigartions` command and then run migrate command.

I have tried using formset but that is not what i am looking for.

refer to [vtiger demo](https://demo.vtiger.com/vtigercrm/index.php?module=LayoutEditor&parent=Settings&view=Index&sourceModule=Assets&mode=showFieldLayout)

username - admin
password - admin

when you open this link there is a option `ADD CUSTOM FIELD`. i want to do same with my django. Hope i am able to explain you what i wants to do. I am searching for this since 3 days and cannot able to implement that.

Comment: you want to create a form which takes fields from model ?

Comment: yes but i want to add more fields dynamically to that model without going back to my pycharm and defining that field again and do migrations. @Moha369

Comment: You can use any one of these Dynamic Models, Json field, Array Field. for your particular requirement.

Comment: @AviKKi I wouldn't advise using any of those solutions  without serious reasons and a full understanding of the implications. And I definitly don't count "i want to add more fields dynamically to that model without going back to my pycharm and defining that field again and do migrations" as a serious reason.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. It helps me alot in doing what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You DO NOT (I repeat: "you **DO NOT**") want to "dynamically add fields" to a model (that is, to your database schema). You want your database **schema** to be stable, known, and totally under version control. If you don't get why, just ask yourself how your code could use a field that it's not even aware of (and that's only one of the oh so many reasons not to do such a thing).

"Features" like the one you mention are built using a fixed schema that is used to describe a "meta schema", where each "custom field" is actually a record in a "custom_fields" table, and then you usually have yet another table to store the matching values. This doesn't come without a lot of code complexity and a huge impact on performances both at the code AND database level.

If this is a project requirement,  you now at least have a first idea of how this is to be done. But if your point is just to avoid having to write code and run migrations, then well, you really want to think twice about it...

Comment: Nothing is impossible (I repeat "Nothing is impossible")

Comment: Yes, everything can be solved by adding a level of indirection... Except for the problem of having too many indirection levels.